# Taking input from JTextField and using it to search arraytable

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I have a `arraylist` which take a `string` e.g. `"String searchFor = "London;"` and then runs runs in the `loop` and then shows data related to the string, if I try change the string to `String searchFor = tfSearch.getText();` then I get `<init>` error

I think problem is that the arraylist doesn't wait for the input to be taken from the JTextField

Comment: could you copy/paste some code? It is very hard to diagnose the problem based on your description.

Comment: You must be using this JTextField.getText(); before the user types anything or clicks any button. I'm guessing you've put this line in the body of constructor.

Comment: Yes I am, but then i get another error for MainApp gui = new MainApp();

Comment: Can you edit your answer with your piece of code? We can't help you If you don't provide us with some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation it says:

```
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the document is null
```

So, your `JTextField` must be `null`.

You need to execute `getText()` on a `actionListener`, for example. Probably, the way you're doing it now, the `JTextField` is `null` yet, and you're not waiting for an input from the user. That way, when the user fills that field and clicks `Enter`, you can get the text from the field.

Check out this example

[Add action listener to JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/AddactionlistenertoJTextField.htm)

Comment: its not called that like that but basically when you launch it, it throws the error, before I even enter anything inside the search JTextField

Comment: Can't you edit your question with a `Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example` of it?